# Where is the Eclipse Sitemap Manager

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sitemap

I can see from the [Eclipse Documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Feditors%2Fsite_editor%2Fsite_map.htm) that there is a sitemap manager to create maps for submitting to Google.  I'm running Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10.0) but can't seem to find the sitemap manager feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reference is the Editor for the `site.xml` file created by the 'File > New > Other > Plug-in Development > Update Site Project' wizard. This is for creating Eclipse RCP update sites.